# estimating heteroskedastic logit model

Tags: r

Suppose (following Train, Discrete Choice Analysis with Simulation, chapter 3.2) you have a discrete choice model, observations from several cities, and you suspect that the variances of the unobserved factors differ over cities. The suggested appropriate
model is heteroskedastic logit (or probit). Can this setup be estimated in R? As far as I can see, the mlogit package doesn't do this
(it doesn't allow you to specify that the source of the heterogeneity is the cities). Is that correct, or am I missing
something? If it is right, any suggestions for an R package?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question: the hetprobit function in package glmx allows you to "model" the sd/variance as a linear function of covariates, which is what I was looking for. The function (despite the name) also allows a logit specification.

Before using the hetprobit model, you may want to read Luke Keele and David Park, "Difficult Choices ...", available via Google Scholar (and probably Google). As far as I can tell, this was not published, which is a pity.